# Browser version detection (opera and chrome complication)

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, cross-browser, opera

I'm trying to detect version using regex of following browsers : Firefox, IE, Opera, Chrome and Safari.

Testing following userAgent information. If push **|Chrome** in regex than the result I am getting is **31.0.1650.63** instead of **18.0.1284.68**

**Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36 OPR/18.0.1284.68** (Opera Browser)

Here is regex :

```
/(?:Firefox|MSIE|Version|OPR).?([0-9.]+)/i
```

This regex working just fine with all browsers which is included , but if I push **|Chrome** in marked expression then chrome and opera versions become complicated . Any advice how I can solve this problem with one regex statement , thanks ...

**NOTE :** Without any library . Question isn't repeated , existence examples uses libraries or kind of different situations

Comment: *"versions become complicated"* - that's why browser detection isn't recommended.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Maybe, but suppose it's possible

Comment: If you could state as to why you are doing this, then others could provide better methods.

Comment: What are you executing the regex on? the title? the navigator name?

Comment: [Should you sniff UA strings?](http://media0.giphy.com/media/GgSlRWjU3NjSU/giphy.gif)

Comment: Even if you find a solution that works for you now, the next time one of the browsers changes their UA string, you'll have to fix it... again. [Detect features instead](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way).